# "Dependant class invalid needs recompilation" error after upgrading to API version 53

Tags: api, managed-package, deployment, error-messages, compile-error

I have upgrade some classes in my org to version 53, while deployment i get the error " Dependant class is invalid needs recompilation".

As per the Salesforce article I have tried compiling all classes and triggers in the org in which upgraded classes are to be deployed but didn't yield any results. Also tries editing and saving the classes but no luck.

Currently I have upgraded only around 500 classes while other classes still stick to the older versions.

Please suggest if u know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Is there another error, particularly in the invalid classes that could be helpful that you could include? Things can sometimes be deprecated between versions.

I did have an issue similar to this after upgrading SFDX recently and the invalid classes were red herrings so that's something to consider too. My solution for that was downgrading to an older SFDX version.

Comment: Hi Shane, yes there are "variable is not visible" errors occasionally for some classes along with the recompilation required error

Comment: What API version were you upgrading from? Also out of interest what is the reason for the upgrade?